# Why do I get a handshake failure between TLS 1.0 client and SSL 3.0 server?

Tags: java, security, ssl, cryptography, jsse

There is a project that uses extensively JSSE.

Depending on a configuration parameter the SSLContext is initialized for `SSLv3`. Meaning that if the parameter is not set it is `SSLv3`, otherwise it is `TLS`.

I noticed some handshake failures occasionally and traced it: If the client negotiated TLS and the server replied with `SSLv3`, the handshake failed

Why does this happen? I thought that TLS and SSLv3 are pretty much interchangeable.
Are they not? If I change server side to always reply `TLS` is there a chance I will break something?

Comment: Is your code the client side or the server side?

Comment: @GregS:I control both sides.But the client part contacts other https servers besides mine as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLS 1.0 is, internally, SSL 3.1. A client and a server *may* accept to use either or both; during the handshake, the client sends the highest protocol version it knows of, and the server *should* select the highest version that it supports that is not always newer than the one sent by the client.

My guess is that when you configure your client to use TLS, then the client understands it as "use *only* TLS 1.0": the client sends "3.1", and if the server is configured to respond with "3.0", then the client will quite logically reject the connection.

What you should do is find a way to configure the server to accept both 3.0 *and* 3.1, and thus use whatever protocol version was announced by the client. Alternatively, configure the client to declare that it knows 3.1, but such that it also accepts a "downgrade" to 3.0 if the server says so.

Comment: So SSL3.1 and 3.0 are not compatible.Is this (usually) configuration i.e. to configure the server to accept both 3.0 and 3.1 or custom code will be required?

Comment: SSL 3.0 and 3.1 are not exactly the same protocol, but they share enough structure that the first client message can work for both, and the server can then decide. This is normally a matter of configuration. Internally, this should end up calling `SSLServerSocket.setEnabledProtocols()` which accepts an array of strings, allowing for the specification of several protocols (e.g. `"SSLv3"` _and_ `"TLSv1"`).

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you are trying to achieve by varying the protocol parameter. SSLv3 and TLS1.0 are very similar but nevertheless distinct protocols. The protocol negotiation mechanism introduced in SSLv3 is also used in subsequent protocols. The bottom line is that in `SSLContext.getInstance("proto");` you should set `proto` to the earliest version of the SSL protocol you are willing to support. After that, the peers will negotiate to use the newest version of the protocol they both support.

Comment: The varying protocol parameter is used as a stricter authentication indication.It is used in other parts as well (e.g. to use more secure number generators etc). My question here is why does the negotiation fails between a server configured for TLS and a client implementation that initializes the SSLContext with SSLv3?